# Removing newline character from a string in Perl

Tags: regex, string, perl

I have a string that is read from a text file, but in Ubuntu Linux, and I try to delete its newline character from the end.

I used all the ways. But for `s/\n|\r/-/` (I look whether it finds any replaces any new line string) it replaces the string, but it still goes to the next line when I print it. Moreover, when I used `chomp` or `chop`, the string is completely deleted. I could not find any other solution. How can I fix this problem?

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.12;
use utf8;
use encoding "utf-8";

open(MYINPUTFILE, "<:encoding(UTF-8)", "file.txt");

my @strings;
my @fileNames;
my @erroredFileNames;

my $delimiter;
my $extensions;
my $id;
my $surname;
my $name;

while (<MYINPUTFILE>)
{
    my ($line) = $_;
    my ($line2) = $_;
    if ($line !~ /^(((\X|[^\W_ ])+)(.docx)(\n|\r))/g) {
        #chop($line2);
        $line2 =~ s/^\n+//;
        print $line2 . " WRONG FORMAT!\n";
    }
    else {
        #print "INSERTED:".$13."\n";
        my($id) = $13;
        my($name) = $2;
        print $name . "\t" . $id . "\n";
        unshift(@fileNames, $line2);
        unshift(@strings, $line2 =~ /[^\W_]+/g);
    }
}
close(MYINPUTFILE);
```

Comment: @TLP Please don’t pretend that Perl character classes have ASCII definitions, because that’s quite wrong in Perl.  You have to use [the definitions from UTS#18 Annex C](http://unicode.org/reports/tr18/#Compatibility_Properties).

Comment: @TLP Yes, of course it isn’t. `\w` is equal to `[\p{Alphabetic}\p{Mark}\p{Decimal_Number}\p{Connector_Punctuation}]`. This is well-known. It covers **102,724 code points** as of Unicode v6.0, which is *four orders of magnitude* more of them than the scant 63 that you mention.

Answer (score 18):

The correct way to remove Unicode linebreak graphemes, including CRLF pairs, is using the `\R` regex metacharacter, introduced in v5.10.

The `use encoding` pragma is strongly deprecated. You should either use the `use open` pragma, or use an encoding in the  mode argument on 3-arg `open`, or use `binmode`.

```
 use v5.10;                     # minimal Perl version for \R support
 use utf8;                      # source is in UTF-8
 use warnings qw(FATAL utf8);   # encoding errors raise exceptions
 use open qw(:utf8 :std);       # default open mode, `backticks`, and std{in,out,err} are in UTF-8

 while (<>) {
     s/\R\z//;
     ...
 }
```

Comment: @stackoverflow Provided you do `$data =~ s/\R//g` that could work; notice I removed the `\z` boundary. Not sure why you want all the newlines gone.

Comment: How about `$/=undef; $data=<MYINPUTFILE>; data=~s/\R//g;` ..?

Comment: @stackoverflow Sure, that’s fine.

Answer (score 12):

You are probably experiencing a line ending from a Windows file causing issues. For example, a string such as "foo bar\n", would actually be "foo bar\r\n". When using `chomp` on Ubuntu, you would be removing whatever is contained in [the variable `$/`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#$/), which would be "\n". So, what remains is "foo bar\r".

This is a subtle, but very common error. For example, if you print "foo bar\r" and add a newline, you would not notice the error:

```
my $var = "foo bar\r\n";
chomp $var;
print "$var\n";  # Remove and put back newline
```

But when you concatenate the string with another string, you overwrite the first string, because `\r` moves the output handle to the beginning of the string. For example:

```
print "$var: WRONG\n";
```

It would effectively be "foo bar\r: WRONG\n", but the text after `\r` would cause the following text to wrap back on top of the first part:

```
foo bar\r           # \r resets position
 : WRONG\n          # Second line prints and overwrites
```

This is more obvious when the first line is longer than the second. For example, try the following:

```
perl -we 'print "foo bar\rbaz\n"'
```

And you will get the output:

```
baz bar
```

The solution is to remove the bad line endings. You can do this with the `dos2unix` command, or directly in Perl with:

```
$line =~ s/[\r\n]+$//;
```

Also, be aware that your other code is somewhat horrific. What do you for example think that `$13` contains? That'd be the string captured by the 13th parenthesis in your previous regular expression. I'm fairly sure that value will always be undefined, because you do not have 13 parentheses.

You declare two sets of `$id` and `$name`. One outside the loop and one at the top. This is very poor practice, IMO. Only declare variables within the scope they need, and never just bunch all your declarations at the top of your script, unless you explicitly *want* them to be global to the file.

Why use `$line` and `$line2` when they have the same value? Just use `$line`.

And seriously, what is up with this:

```
if ($line !~ /^(((\X|[^\W_ ])+)(.docx)(\n|\r))/g) {
```

That looks like an attempt to obfuscate, no offence. Three nested negations and a bunch of unnecessary parentheses?

First off, since it is an if-else, just swap it around and reverse the regular expression. Second, `[^\W_]` a double negation is rather confusing. Why not just use `[A-Za-z0-9]`? You can split this up to make it easier to parse:

```
if ($line =~ /^(.+)(\.docx)\s*$/) {
    my $pre = $1;
    my $ext = $2;
```

Answer (score 7):

You can wipe the linebreaks with something like this:

```
$line =~ s/[\n\r]//g;
```

When you do that though, you'll need to change the regex in your `if` statement to not look for them. I also don't think you want a `/g` in your `if`. You really shouldn't have a `$line2` either.

I also wouldn't do this type of thing:

```
print $line2." WRONG FORMAT!\n";
```

You can do

```
print "$line2 WRONG FORMAT!\n";
```

... instead. Also, print accepts a list, so instead of concatenating your strings, you can just use commas.

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like:

`=~ tr/\n//`

But really `chomp` should work:

```
while (<filehandle>){
   chomp;
   ...
}
```

---

Also `s/\n|\r//` only replaces the first occurrence of `\r` or `\n`.  If you wanted to replace all occurrences you would want the global modifier at the end `s/\r|\n//g`.

Note: if you're including `\r` for windows it usually ends its line as `\r\n` so you would want to replace both (e.g. `s/(?:\r\n|\n)//`), of course the statement above (`s/\r|\n//g`) with the global modifier would take care of that anyways.

Answer (score 3):

```
$variable = join('',split(/\n/,$variable))
```