# How to Extract the string between double quotes having newline embedded in between the string?

Tags: regex, perl

I want to extract the text between the `"` quotation marks and append them. While ignoring the newlines embedded in the string.

What I have so far is something like:

```
$whole_text="\"Ankit Stackoverflow is \n awesome\" \"a\" asd asd \"he\nllo\"\n";

while ($whole_text=~ /(.*?)"(.*?)"(.*?)/m)
{ 
    $whole_text=~ s/(.*?)"(.*?)"(.*?)/$2/m;
}
```

Expected result:

```
Ankit Stackoverflow is awesome and hello
```

Comment: INPUT is $whole_text="\"Ankit Stackoverflow is \n awesome\" \"a\" asd asd \"he\nllo\"\n";

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing newline character from a string in Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9751161/removing-newline-character-from-a-string-in-perl)

Comment: @KyleFairns though `\n` removal is covered in the linked answer, it does not answer the match between quotes.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard From the example given, it just seems like they want to remove all `\n` characters. Perhaps this could be clarified by the asker?

Comment: _"How to Extract the **string between double quotes** having newline embedded in between the string?_"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're using the wrong modifier on your regex. The `/m` treats the string has multiple lines where you actually want to use `/s` which changes "." to match any character including `\n`.

Changing this won't actually get you the output you want because you're repeatedly applying the transformation and it will delete any past quoted portions too. You want to also use the `/g` modifier which will find all possible matches and then only apply the regex the once.

```
use strict;

my $whole_text="\"Ankit Stackoverflow is \n awesome\" \"a\" asd asd \"he\nllo\"\n";

$whole_text =~ s/(.*?)"(.*?)"(.*?)/$2/sg;
```

And then if you want to get rid of the `\n` you'd also need.

```
$whole_text =~ s/\n//sg;
```